# Rails Dev Environment - Any Tips?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, development-environment, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I'm using the ruby environment on my host via ssh and all my development goes through sublimeText2.

Problem is that i have to download the files manually, change them and upload them. It's possible so setup a dropboxsync with my server but this is not the finest way to work on my rails.

Is there a nice solution to get a sweet workflow?

Edit: Ubuntu Machine here

Comment: I don't quite understand - why not develop locally & use version control to control what ends up on your server ?

Comment: You can use version control system like git.

Comment: installing and using rails on ubuntu is not that handsome, so i wanne use the enviroment from my hoster which runs error free. Also performance is not that high on my notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought about sshfs?  That will give you a directory on your local machine that "is" a directory on the remote machine.  Then you can edit the files "locally" and not even notice that they're on another machine.

```
sshfs user@remotehost:/remote/path localdirectory
```

Comment: Seems to be the best solution for me, its also more secure than dropbox ... thanks